# To use dynamic values in condition of handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars to render my webpage however while doing an "if" condition checking, it's not working for dynamic arguments. I am external libraries

```
    var helpers = require('handlebars-helpers');
var compare = helpers.comparison({
    hbs: hbs
  });
```

and trying to render

```
  res.render('event.hbs', {
        name: req.user.displayName,
        event:data,
        eventName:req.params.event
    });
}
```

and my handlebar login in webpage

```
{{#each event}}
    {{#each this.events}}
    {{#is this.event eventName}}
    <div class="col s4">{{this.imageId}}</div>
    {{!-- {{else}}
    <div class="col s4">{{this.imageId}}</div> --}}
    {{/is}}
    {{/each}}
 {{/each}}
```

When i replace the "eventName" in webpage with some known string which will make condition true the page works properly. However, when i try to render "eventName" dynamically nothing shows.
How can i make it work?

This is my structure of data of one document, i have multiple of those in a collection

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a977c1d8b0265ece5c8921c"),
    "Fbid" : "113161819515501",
    "__v" : 0,
    "events" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a977c1db9ada731386488c5"),
            "event" : "selfie",
            "imageId" : "eklxnjb9if"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a977c50b9ada731386488c6"),
            "event" : "sing",
            "imageId" : "5bdns7lrkc6"
        }
    ],
    "email" : "pigspdsude_1519876920@tfbnw.net"
}
```

Comment: what is `req.param.event`?

Comment: its a part of the url

Comment: Anad what is its value? Is `console.log(req.param.event)` showing what you expect?

Comment: Am i doing right thing, is it allowed in handlebars, till now every example i have seen uses normal string in comparision

Comment: let me check again.

Comment: yes...it is showing

Comment: I think there may be some sort of data structure mismatch. Looking at this code, I think the logic is that you pass `data` to render, which is an array of `events`. Each item in the array then has another `event` property? What is the structure of `data`?

Comment: M posting it above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your handlebars file, change `eventName` to `../../eventName`

The nested each is making your variables out of scope :)

Comment: Tried, not working, data is an array of document received by mongo query

Comment: No, mongoose is i guess returning everything fine, coz when i replace the "eventName" with event like "Selfie" i get the correct output.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Perfect...however, on a side note, where did you get this?